# javascript paired values array access

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have an array of paired values

```
1:9,10:8,20:7
```

representing quantities and prices/price breaks which I want to iterate through to establish the correct price point to use when a particular quantity is ordered.

```
var qty = parseFloat($("#qtyInput").val());
var price_array = $("#sku_price_array" + sel_class).val();
var sku_price_array = price_array.split(",");
for (var i=0; i<sku_price_array.length; i++) {
    var sku_prices = sku_price_array[i].split(":");
    if (qty > sku_prices[i][0]) {
        alert(sku_prices[i][1]);
    };
};
```

My alert is not showing the values I intended.

What I'm aiming for is getting the value 1 for `sku_prices[i][0]` on the first run through, and alerting the value 9 from `sku_prices[i][1]`.

On my first run-through, firebug shows my sku_prices[i][0] value to be 1, but the alert is undefined.

(edit:escape characters removed, thank you)

Comment: If your array really is like in your example, you have an error message in the console... Or is it actually a string?

Comment: why do you have escape sequences for the quotes in `split`? It could be causing your error

Comment: `sku_prices` isn't a double array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sku_prices` isn't a two-dimensional array. Omit the `[i]` and it should work.

Comment: Thank you very much.  That was the ticket.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: @user2187710 sure thing. Also, as far as I can tell, the semicolons after your `if` and `for` blocks don't do anything. You can remove them if you want